# How to create a link to sections on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck at moving to a section on the same page which in my case is the #iframe, located at the bottom of the page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle_message').click(function() {
    var value = $('#toggle_message').attr('value');
    $('#iframe').toggle('fast');

    if (value == 'Vise Reserver Bord Her') {
      $('#toggle_message').attr('value', 'Skjule Reservation');

    } else if (value == 'Skjule Reservation') {
      $('#toggle_message').attr('value', 'Vise Reserver Bord Her');
    }

  })
  $("#toggle-message").click(function() {
    window.location.hash = "#" + $(this).attr("#iframe");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="booking">
  <input type="button" value="Vise Reserver Bord Her" id="toggle_message" />

</div>
<div id="column"> images here </div>
<div id="column_Two"> text boxes </div>
<div id="iframe_box">
  <iframe id="iframe" src="link"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Show what the basic html looks like. Curious if those are 2 different elements or one is spelled wrong. Also what the iframe attr looks like. Not normal to have an attribute start with `#`

Comment: The html is looking somehow like that. by cliking the button i want to open the iframe which in css is display:none to show: this happens how ever i cannot jump to the iframe section

Comment: WHere's `('#toggle_message')` or `$("#toggle-message")`? you keep looking for `attr()` on those elements and without seeing them is hard to tell what is going on

Comment: `$("#iframe_box")[0].scrollIntoView();`

Comment: #toggle_message is the id of the input button by clicking the input button, the iframe does toggle. What i want with the toggle is the jump to the bottom of the iframe location which is at the bottom of the same page.

Comment: nnnnnn $("#iframe_box")[0].scrollIntoView(); did not work out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you everybody i found the solution :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('#toggle_message').click(function(){
    var value= $('#toggle_message').attr('value');
    $('#iframe').toggle('fast');
    location.href="#iframe";
    if(value=='Vise Reserver Bord Her') {
        $('#toggle_message').attr('value','Skjule Reservation');

    }else if(value=='Skjule Reservation'){
        $('#toggle_message').attr('value','Vise Reserver Bord Her');
location.href="#timing";
    }

})

});
```